# Demonstrate passing jQuery object to Web api through Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

i am new to jQuery,Ajax,Web Api .Please find me demonstration for **passing jQuery object to Web api through Ajax call**

Thankis in advance.
Sunil Jadhav

Comment: try this http://bit.ly/1hRdwAm

Answer (score 2):

More info in here:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/Home/Index',
  data: {id:1},
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){
     console.log(data);//  return from webapi 
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Or could send a JSON string then catch it on server side so it can be use as a (assuming server side is php) converted to an array play with and return a a JSON so get reconvert into JQuery object

Comment: A sample of the webapi's action would help :P

Comment: could you give me demonstration, any where on net or sample project- Thanks in advance

Comment: @SunilJadhav http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424461/Implementing-Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-from-JQuery